# How to backup Peewee database (SqliteQueueDatabase) programatically?

Tags: python, sqlite, peewee

I'm using Peewee in one of my projecs. Specifically, I'm using `SqliteQueueDatabase` and I need to create a backup (i.e. another *.db file) without stopping my application. I saw that there are two methods that could work for me (`backup` and `backup_to_file`) but they're methods from `CSqliteExtDatabase`, and `SqliteQueueDatabase` is subclass of `SqliteExtDatabase`. I've found solutions to manually create a dump of the file, but I need a *.db file (not a *.csv file, for example). Couldn't find any similar question or relevant answer.

Thanks!

Comment: Can't you just copy the file?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can just import the `backup_to_file()` helper from `playhouse._sqlite_ext` and pass it your connection and a filename:

```
db = SqliteQueueDatabase('...')

from playhouse._sqlite_ext import backup_to_file
conn = db.connection()  # get the underlying pysqlite conn
backup_to_file(conn, 'dest.db')
```

Also, if you're using pysqlite3, then there are also backup methods available on the connection itself.

Comment: Great, that worked perfectly for me. Couldn't find that much in the docs about `backup_to_file`, except what I already cited. Anyways, thanks for the answer. Also, I really admire the great work you do supporting your own library, I've found your answers everywhere and it's really inspiring to see. Thanks again!

Comment: @coleifer what if I can't use cython? In fact, why is this method only available in CSqliteExtDatabase?